# How to scrape multiple selectors and group them

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, css-selectors, html-agility-pack

I'm wanting to scrape this page: https://www.g2crowd.com/products/google-analytics/reviews (For my own education)

```
    // @nuget: HtmlAgilityPack
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument html = web.Load("https://www.g2crowd.com/products/google-analytics/reviews");
        var textNodes = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3[contains(@class,'review-list-heading')]");
        if (textNodes != null)
            foreach (var t in textNodes)
                Console.WriteLine(t.InnerText);
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far, which pulls every review heading perfectly. But how in the world would I scape the heading & the review body - making it clear that each review is seperate?

The review "body" (meaning text) being:
 `//*[@id="pjax-container"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div`in xpath.

Or `<div itemprop="reviewBody">` in pure html.

This is a dotnetfiddle of what I have currently: https://dotnetfiddle.net/30Y0M6

Please ask if I'm not being clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select parent container which are `<div class="mb-2 border-bottom">` then select the child

```
// @nuget: HtmlAgilityPack
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument html = web.Load("https://www.g2crowd.com/products/google-analytics/reviews");
        var divNodes = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='mb-2 border-bottom']");
        if (divNodes != null)
        {
            foreach (var child in divNodes)
            {
                var allowedTags = child.SelectNodes(".//h3 | .//h5 | .//p");
                foreach (var tag in allowedTags)
                    Console.WriteLine(tag.InnerText);
                Console.WriteLine("======================================");
            }
        }
    }
}
```